Configuring the Highcharts Library slider (stocks)
I have a stock chart of the Highcharts library. How to adjust the position of the right and left slider in the picture. I need that when I click on the "now" button, the left slider moves to today's date, and the right one is at a distance from it, for example, 3 hours enter image description here
As I understood in this library, the position of the left slider is dancing from the position of the right one. I implemented moving the left slider for the number of seconds I needed. But it's dancing from the same right-hand runner...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@dockercompose , hello. There is no code. There is a library for charting Highcharts. There is the creation of Stock charts with "navigator". It has sliders (marked in the picture in the question). It is necessary that when you click on the button, the left slider goes away for the time that is now. The right slider was 3 hours away from it

You are looking for the setExtremes method. You can use it in the click event as below:
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [..., {
      text: 'now',
      title: 'View current date',
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          const now = new Date().getTime();
          chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(now, now + HOUR * 3);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }]
  }


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5gvdy8oa/
API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons.events.click
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes
